# Number of solutions of nonlinear system

Tags: equation-solving

How can we know the number of solutions of nonlinear system with many parameters by using *Mathematica* program?
I have

```
H1[x_, y_] = ((-1 + c1 + a1 x + b1 y)^2 (c1^2 + c2^2 + x (2 a2 c2 + 
             (a1^2 + a2^2) x) + 2 (a1 b1 x + b2 (c2 + a2 x)) y + (b1^2 + b2^2) y^2 
              + 2 c1 (a1 x + b1 y)))/(-1 + 2 c1 + 2 a1 x + 2 b1 y)^2

H2[x_, y_] = ((-1 + x m1 + y n1 + h1)^2 (y^2 (n1^2 + n2^2) + 2 (x m1 + y n1) h1 + 
              h1^2 + h2^2 + x (x (m1^2 + m2^2) + 2 m2 h2) + 2 y (x m1 n1 + n2 (x m2 
              + h2))))/(-1 + 2 x m1 + 2 y n1 + 2 h1)^2;
```

I want to know the number of solution of the system E1=0 and E2=0 with

```
E1=H1[0, y1] - H1[0, y2]......and E2=H2[0, y1] - H2[0, y2].
```

Comment: `Length@Solve[sys, vars]` is one way. -- Or more safely, `Solve[sys, vars] /. {{{}} -> Infinity, sols_List :> Length[sols]`

Comment: Thank you so much I will try it to see the result

Comment: Look up `Reduce`. Without more details about what types of equations you have, this question is not really answerable.

Comment: This does not have sufficient information. Are these polynomial systems? What would be a representative example (in Mathematica format)? Absent such necessary details, questions like this on MSE (that one from 2-3 days ago, for example) generally get closed.

Comment: I have H1[x_, y_] = ((-1 + c1 + a1 x + b1 y)^2 (c1^2 + c2^2 + 
     x (2 a2 c2 + (a1^2 + a2^2) x) + 
     2 (a1 b1 x + b2 (c2 + a2 x)) y + (b1^2 + b2^2) y^2 + 
     2 c1 (a1 x + b1 y)))/(-1 + 2 c1 + 2 a1 x + 2 b1 y)^2; and    H2[x_, y_] = ((-1 + x m1 + y n1 + h1)^2 (y^2 (n1^2 + n2^2) + 
     2 (x m1 + y n1) h1 + h1^2 + h2^2 + 
     x (x (m1^2 + m2^2) + 2 m2 h2) + 
     2 y (x m1 n1 + n2 (x m2 + h2))))/(-1 + 2 x m1 + 2 y n1 + 2 h1)^2;; I want to know the number of solution of the system E1=0 and E2=0 with E1=H1[0, y1] - H1[0, y2]......and E2=H2[0, y1] - H2[0, y2].

Comment: I have the condition that y1 different to y2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can rewrite and simplify a bit by factoring.

```
hH1[x_, y_] := ((-1 + c1 + a1 x + b1 y)^2 (c1^2 + c2^2 + 
      x (2 a2 c2 + (a1^2 + a2^2) x) + 
      2 (a1 b1 x + b2 (c2 + a2 x)) y + (b1^2 + b2^2) y^2 + 
      2 c1 (a1 x + b1 y)))/(-1 + 2 c1 + 2 a1 x + 2 b1 y)^2; 
hH2[x_, y_] := ((-1 + x m1 + y n1 + h1)^2 (y^2 (n1^2 + n2^2) + 
      2 (x m1 + y n1) h1 + h1^2 + h2^2 + 
      x (x (m1^2 + m2^2) + 2 m2 h2) + 
      2 y (x m1 n1 + n2 (x m2 + h2))))/(-1 + 2 x m1 + 2 y n1 + 
     2 h1)^2;
```

Here are the expressions we want to set to zero. We will solve for numerators vanishing. We need to obtain also the list of parameters (the symbolic entities that we do not solve for).

```
exprs = 
  Numerator[
   Together[{hH1[0, y1] - hH1[0, y2], hH2[0, y1] - hH2[0, y2]}]];
vars = {y1, y2};
params = Complement[Variables[exprs], vars]

(* Out[87]= {b1, b2, c1, c2, h1, h2, n1, n2} *)
```

First factor the expressions. It will turn out that `y2-y1` is a factor to both (no surprise, given the construction). We will remove that common factor before solving.

```
e2 = Map[FactorList, exprs];
Map[Length, e2]
e2[[All, 1 ;; 2]]

(* Out[92]= {3, 3}

Out[93]= {{{1, 1}, {y1 - y2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {y1 - y2, 1}}} *)
```

So each has a third factor and no more than that. We extract those third factors. Since the interest is in counting solutions, we obtain the generic count by solving with a random set of values substituted for the parameters. We solve numerically to modest prtecision; this does a good jpob of getting the correct number of solutions.

```
randomsubsts = 
  RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}, Length[params]]/
   RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, Length[params]];

nsols = 
  NSolve[newexprs /. Thread[params -> randomsubsts], vars, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 100];
Length[nsols]

(* Out[98]= 16 *)
```

So there will be 16 solutions for generic values of the parameters (which means, the exceptions will comprise a set of measure zero). Here are the solutions for this particular set of parameter values.

```
In[99]:= N@nsols

(* Out[99]= {{y1 -> 0.185522, y2 -> -143.886}, {y1 -> 0.186196, 
  y2 -> -138.976}, {y1 -> 0.185501, y2 -> 134.688}, {y1 -> 0.18622, 
  y2 -> 129.45}, {y1 -> -143.886, y2 -> 0.185522}, {y1 -> -138.976, 
  y2 -> 0.186196}, {y1 -> 134.688, y2 -> 0.185501}, {y1 -> 129.45, 
  y2 -> 0.18622}, {y1 -> -0.256513 + 1.69563 I, 
  y2 -> -0.256513 - 1.69563 I}, {y1 -> -0.256513 - 1.69563 I, 
  y2 -> -0.256513 + 1.69563 I}, {y1 -> 0.162475 + 0.0454512 I, 
  y2 -> 0.162475 - 0.0454512 I}, {y1 -> 0.162475 - 0.0454512 I, 
  y2 -> 0.162475 + 0.0454512 I}, {y1 -> -0.148865 + 0.164069 I, 
  y2 -> -0.148865 - 0.164069 I}, {y1 -> -0.148865 - 0.164069 I, 
  y2 -> -0.148865 + 0.164069 I}, {y1 -> 0.0573625 + 0.176119 I, 
  y2 -> 0.0573625 - 0.176119 I}, {y1 -> 0.0573625 - 0.176119 I, 
  y2 -> 0.0573625 + 0.176119 I}} *)
```

Eight are real valued. In general there might be different counts of real-valued solutions for different parameter values.

Comment: I need to read your solution to understand it, Tha,k you so much sir.

Comment: Sir, Can I understand that this system has only 8 real solutions for any values of the parameters  a1,a2,b1, b2, c1, c2, h1, h2, n1, n2,m1,m2?

Comment: @Sarayaqob  Probably not

Comment: Counting real solutions is (unfortunately) much more difficult. About all I can say is that for parameters in in some neighborhood of the values I chose, there will be exactly eight real solutions. Finding boundaries where this might change gets into what is called the discriminant. For this system I suspect even computing the discriminant might be prohibitive. Actually using it to decompose into parameter space regions of fixed number of real solutions is almost certainly not tractable.

Comment: Thank you sir four your help, I use your program and I found 16 real solutions. Thank you again.